# Can there be more betting after an all-in covering a min raise amount?

Tags: rules

Say player A initially raises the bet to 2200, player B re-raises to 5200, player C calls 5200, and players D and E fold. Player A then shoves all-in for 8200 total. Does this open the betting round for player B to re-raise?

Comment: Yes, and by precisely the minimum. The betting was 2200 + 3000 + 3000. If that last amount had been less than 3000, then the betting would be closed.

Answer (score 5):

According to the World Series of Poker No-Limit & Pot-Limit rules page, **yes**, player B has the option to reraise because it is **just** enough to reopen the betting round.

> All raises must be equal to or greater than the size of the previous bet or raise on that betting round, except for an all-in wager. A player who has already acted and is not facing a fullsize wager may not subsequently raise an all-in bet that is less than the minimum bet (which is the amount of the minimum bring-in), **or less than the full size of the last bet or raise.** (The half-the-size rule for reopening the betting is for limit poker only.) Example: Player A bets $100 and Player B raises $100 more, making the total bet $200. If Player C goes all in for less than $300 total (not a full $100 raise), and Player A calls, then Player B has no option to raise again, because he wasn't fully raised. (Player A could have raised, because Player B raised.)

So, in this case:

> Player A raised to `$2200`
>   Player B reraises `$3000` to make the total bet `$5200`
>   Player C calls `$5200`
>   Player A reraises `$3000` to make the total bet `$8200`

Thus, player A only needed to raise `$3000` to open the betting round again — which he did.